# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a music player, so i want when the user closes the app, save the position of the song he was listening, to do that i just run a function in the componentWillUnmount in `Track zone component`, this one:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        TrackPlayer.addEventListener("playback-track-changed", this.get_actual_track);
        TrackPlayer.addEventListener("playback-queue-ended", this.get_queue_option);
        this.init();
    }
  
   componentWillUnmount() {
      this.save_position();
   }

    save_position = async() => {
        status = await TrackPlayer.getState();
        console.log(status);
        if (status === 3 || status === 8 || status === 2) {
            let position = await TrackPlayer.getPosition();
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("last_song_duration", JSON.stringify(position));
            await TrackPlayer.pause();
            TrackPlayer.destroy();
        }else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

sometimes it saves it, and sometimes it doenst, think it has something to do with it, but dont know what, when i open the app, this is the first component that loads everything:

in App I have `Tab navigator`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
```

render() {
return (
<>
<Tab_Navigator></Tab_Navigator>
</>
);
}
}

this is `tab navigator`

```
   componentDidMount() {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener("playback-track-changed", this.play_selected_music);
    this.requestPermission();
}

requestPermission = async () => {
    try {
        const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
            [
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            ],
        );
        if (permission["android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED 
            && permission["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            try {
                let tracks = [];
                let tracks_object = []; 
                tracks = await MusicFiles.getAll({
                    cover: true,
                });
                let length = tracks.length;
                for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
                    tracks_object.push(new Tracks_info(tracks.results[i]));
                }
                this.setState({tracks: tracks_object}, () => this.init_player());
            }catch(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }else {
            this.requestPermission();
        }
    }catch (error) {
        alert(error)
    }
};

init_player = async () => {
    
    try {
        if (this.random) {
            let tracks = this.random_queue();
            await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
            await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({ stopWithApp: true });
            await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
            this.setState({random_tracks: tracks, init: true});
        }else {
            let tracks = this.state.tracks;
            await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
            await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({stopWithApp: true});
            await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
            this.setState({init: true});
        }
    }catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

its render method:

```
 <NavigationContainer>
                    <Tab.Navigator>
                        <Tab.Screen name = "Tracks" children = {({navigation}) => <Tracks navigation = {navigation} tracks = {this.state.tracks}></Tracks>}></Tab.Screen>
                        <Tab.Screen name = "PlayList" children = {({navigation}) => <PlayList navigation = {navigation} tracks = {this.state.tracks}></PlayList>}></Tab.Screen>
                    </Tab.Navigator>
                    <BottomSheet
                        ref = {ref => (this.sheetref = ref)}
                        initialSnap = {1}
                        snapPoints = {[Dimensions.get("window").height - StatusBar.currentHeight, 95]}
                        renderHeader = {() => <Player_Header {...props}></Player_Header>}
                        renderContent = {() => <Track_Zone {...props}></Track_Zone>}
                        enabledContentGestureInteraction = {false}
                        onOpenEnd = {this.hide_icon}
                        onCloseEnd = {this.show_icon}>
                    </BottomSheet>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: I dont see  componentWillUnmount function anywhere in your code ?

Comment: @NikhilPonduri  my bad, edited

Comment: can you try removing the eventListeners that you have added in componentDidMount. ```TrackPlayer.removeEventListener("playback-track-changed");```.

Comment: @NikhilPonduri doesnt work